# Why doesn't String.Join add separator on loop

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I show the categories of my **i'th** product on the View, but I want to put commas between them.

My view

[image]

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Products.Count(); i++)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            <span> @Model.Products[i].ProductName </span>
            @foreach (var item in Model.Products[i].ProductCategories)
            {
                <span>@string.Join(", ", item.Category.CategoryName)</span>
            }
        </td>
   </tr>
```

[image]

Why is String.Join not working what am I missing

I want this

**Computer, Technology, Desktop**

Comment: well, `item.Category.CategoryName` is _just one element_. for joining, you need at least _two_ element, so the comma can be inbetween. cut out your foreach and select the categorynames in one array instead.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann thanks i don't know how i missed this

Answer (score 1):

`item.Category.CategoryName` represents only single category name that's why on joining no `,` (comma) were added. If you want to join all ProductCategories, then use the below code

```
<tr>
        <td>
            <span> @Model.Products[i].ProductName </span>
            <span>@string.Join(", ", Model.Products[i].ProductCategories.Select(p => p.Category.CategoryName))</span>
        </td>
   </tr>
```

The above code will iteration over all `ProductCategories` and join those using `string.Join`